# Guardar dados na base de dados usando Form no CakePHP

Tags: php, sql, upload, formulário, cakephp-2

Estou a tentar fazer uma ferramenta para o administrador, do site que estou a construir, que permita fazer o upload de imagens para uma pasta no servidor, para que estas aparecam postreriormente na galeria. O upload da imagem está a funcionar correctamente, no entanto o nome desta não é inserido na base de dados. Este deveria ser inserido na tabela "gallery_images", no campo "path". Como se pode resolver este problema?

Estou utilizando o CakePHP 2.4.4

**Controller**

```
    <?php
class AdminsController extends AppController{

    public $components = array('RequestHandler');
    public function admin_index(){
        if(!$this->Session->check('Admin')){
        $this->Session->setFlash('Está a aceder a uma zona restrita. Por favor faça Login.');
        $this->redirect(array(
                                'controller' => 'admins',
                                'action' => 'login'));
        }
        $this->layout='admin_index';
    }
    public function add_foto() {            
        if(!$this->Session->check('Admin')){
        $this->Session->setFlash('Está a aceder a uma zona restrita. Por favor faça Login.');
        $this->redirect(array(
                                'controller' => 'admins',
                                'action' => 'login'));
        }
        $this->layout='admin_index';
        $file=$this->request->data['gallery_images']['path'];
        if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')){
                $this->Admin->create();
            $this->Admin->save($file);
            move_uploaded_file($this->data['gallery_images']['path']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/html/PushUp_app/app/webroot/img/gallery/' . $this->data['gallery_images']['path']['name']);
                     if($this->Admin->save($this->request->data)){
                     $this->Session->setFlash(__('Ficheiro carregado com sucesso!'));
            }
        }
        //$this->Admin->id = $id;
        //$this->Post->save($data=array($this->data['Admins']['path']), $params=array('fieldList'=>'path'));
        //$this->Post->saveField('path', $this->data['Admins']['path']);
            /*if ($this->ModelName->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Data Saved!');
            }*/
        //if($this->request->is('post')){
        //  $this->Admin->save($this->request->data);
            //}
        //}
    }
}
    ?>
```

**View**

```
    <h2>Adicionar Fotografia</h2>
    <?php
echo "<br>";
echo $this->Form->create('Admin',array('type'=>'file'));
echo $this->Form->file('gallery_images.path');
echo "<br>";
//echo $this->Form->submit();
echo $this->Form->end('Guardar');

    ?>
```

[Tabela gallery_images](http://i64.photobucket.com/albums/h184/SunTzu1988/bd_gallery_images_struct_zpsf4e4a05e.png)

[Tabela admins](http://i64.photobucket.com/albums/h184/SunTzu1988/bd_admins_struct_zps067654a1.png)

## **Código Certo**

**Controller**

```
    <?php
    class GalleryController extends AppController {

    public function admin_upload_image(){
        $this->layout = 'admin_index';
        if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
          /*  $file = $this->request->data['gallery_images']['path']['name'];*/
        $file = array(
                'GalleryImage' => array(
                'path' => $this->request->data['gallery_images']['path']['name']
                                        )
                );
            move_uploaded_file($this->data['gallery_images']['path']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/html/PushUp_app/app/webroot/img/gallery/' . $this->data['gallery_images']['path']['name']);

            $this->loadModel('GalleryImage');
            $this->GalleryImage->create();

            if($this->GalleryImage->save($file)){
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Ficheiro carregado com sucesso!'));
            }
            else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Erro ao carregar o ficheiro!'));
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**View**

```
    <h2>Adicionar Fotografia</h2>
    <?php
echo "<br>";
echo $this->Form->create('GalleryImage',array('type'=>'file'));
echo $this->Form->file('gallery_images.path');
echo "<br>";
//echo $this->Form->submit();
echo $this->Form->end('Guardar');

    ?>
```

**Model**

```
    <?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class GalleryImage extends AppModel{
    public $displayField ='path';
    public $useTable = 'gallery_images';
}
    ?>
```

Comment: O que a função ´Admin->save()´ está fazendo?

Comment: @Lucio Deveria escrever na base de dados.

Comment: Pode mostrar a estrutura da tabela `admin`?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues já adicionei ao post, no fundo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por partes.

### 1 - Quem é o seu Model?

- Admin?
- gallery_images?

**Se for gallery_images** está completamente incorreto pelos **padrões do CakePHP**.

O correto seria **GalleryImage**.

---

### 2 - Você está tentando salvar a imagem em qual MODEL?

#### No model Admin?

Se for no **Admin**, você deve corrigir o seu array `$file`, para atender a sua necessidade:

```
$file = array(
  'Admin' => array(
    'path' => $this->request->data['gallery_images']['path']['name']
  )
);
```

Lembrando que deve validar se no seu model **Admin** tem a propriedade:

```
public $table = 'gallery_images';
```

#### No model GalleryImage?

Se for **GalleryImage**, deve também corrígi-lo:

```
$file = array(
  'GalleryImage' => array(
    'path' => $this->request->data['gallery_images']['path']['name']
  )
);
```

**Lembrando** que sou model **GalleryImage** deve seguir o modelo abaixo:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * GalleryImage Model
 *
 */
class GalleryImage extends AppModel {

  public $displayField = 'name';
  public $useTable = 'gallery_images';

}
```

---

### 3 - porque alterar o `$file`?

Pelo que eu entendi, no seu código você está fazendo o seguinte:

```
$file = $this->request->data['gallery_images']['path']['name'];
```

Com isso você criou uma variável com 1 valor `x` e está salvando ela.

O problema é que você não está dizendo ao CakePHP, **que campo é esse**, e muito menos **a que Model pertence**. Então o correto seria:

```
$file = array(
  'NomeDoModel' => array(
    'nome_do_campo' => 'valor_do_campo'
  )
);
```

Com isso você montou/criou o array de maneira correta e o CakePHP consegue agora entender que você quer salvar no model X os campos A, B e C.

---

### 4 - Porque você está executando 2 saves? [Dúvida]

No seu código você executa `$this->Admin->save($file);`  e depois `$this->Admin->save($this->request->data);`.

Realmente não entendi a necessidade disso. Porém o que você está fazendo executando isso é:

- Insert
- Update do registro já inserido

---

### 5 - Upload da imagem

Recomendo utilizar a biblioteca [Wide Image](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/) para fazer o upload, crop e resize das suas imagens.

É incrivelmente fácil de implamantar no CakePHP, esteja ela integrado ou não com o **composer**.

### 6 - Código corrigido**

Seu código, deve ficar mais ou menos assim, dependendo se você está usando o model **Admin ou GalleryImage**, se a as últimas linhas (segundo save) estão corretas ou não:

```
public function add_foto() {            
  if(!$this->Session->check('Admin')) {

    $this->Session->setFlash('Está a aceder a uma zona restrita. Por favor faça Login.');
    $this->redirect(array(
      'controller' => 'admins',
      'action' => 'login'));
  }

  $this->layout = 'admin_index';

  $file = array(
    'GalleryImage' => array(
      'path' => $this->request->data['gallery_images']['path']['name']
    )
  );

  if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {

    $this->loadModel('GalleryImage');
    $this->GalleryImage->save($file);

    move_uploaded_file($this->data['gallery_images']['path']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/html/PushUp_app/app/webroot/img/gallery/' . $this->data['gallery_images']['path']['name']);

    // Não sei o que você está tentando fazer aqui, por isso comentei o código
    // if($this->Admin->save($this->request->data)) {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Ficheiro carregado com sucesso!'));
    //}

  }
}
```

---

---

---

## Rotas Administrativas

Partindo pelo pressuposto que há uma clara dificuldade quanto ao entendimento de área administrativa **(Rotas Administrativas)**, vou tentar explicar a forma correta da maneira mais simples e prática possível como realmente funciona.

### Configurando a rota principal `/admin`

Vamos dizer que você queria que a rota `/admin` seja somente visível para usuários presentes no grupo (perfil) **Administrador**, e com isso, exiga o login ao acessar qualquer sub-rota.

Para que isso funcione da melhor forma possível, vamos utilizar **prefixos**.

O que você deve fazer então é... no seu `app/Config/routes.php`, adicionar o seguinte código:

```
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'dashboard', 'admin' => true));
```

Dessa forma estou dizendo: ao acessar a url `http://www.example.com/admin`, o CakePHP deverá chamar a action `dashboard` do controller `pages`, porém essa rota tem **o prefixo admin** antes do nome, o que seria no caso isso:

```
class PagesController extends AppController {
  public function admin_dashboard() {
    // código aqui
  }
}
```

### Configurando outras rotas administrativas

Além disso, vamos dizer que esse **usuário no grupo Administrador**, também pode fazer upload de imagens **(GalleryImage)**. Então vamos criar a action:

```
class GalleryImagesController extends AppController {
  public function admin_upload_image() {
    // código aqui
  }
}

class GalleryImage extends AppModel {
  public $table = 'gallery_images';
  public $displayField = 'name';
  // código aqui
}
```

Com isso nós temos a rota:

```
http://www.example.com/admin/gallery_images/upload_image
```

Caso queria customizar essa rota, basta fazer o seguinte em seu routes:

```
Router::connect('/admin/galeria-de-imagens/enviar', array('controller' => 'gallery_images', 'action' => 'upload_image', 'admin' => true));
```

Com isso nós temos agora a rota:

```
http://www.example.com/admin/galeria-de-imagens/enviar
```

Para criar mais rotas administrativas em diferentes controllers, basta seguir o exemplo acima.

### Limitando o acesso somente a usuários logados

Mas fazendo só isso estou garantindo alguma coisa? **NÃO!**.

Agora temos que dizer ao `app/Config/AppController.php`, que as rotas administrativas exigem login. Para isso vamos utilizar 2 métodos:

-`beforeFilter()` do próprio CakePHP
-`isPrefix()` apenas para auxiliar a obter o prefixo atual da URL

```
public function beforeFilter() {
  if($this->isPrefix('admin')) {

    // Seta o layout admin para as rotas administrativas
    $this->layout = 'admin';

  } else {

    // Utilizando o método abaixo, permite o acesso as URLs 
    // sem o login (Auth do CakePHP)
    $this->Auth->allow();

  }
}

public function isPrefix($prefix) {
  return isset($this->request->params['prefix']) 
    && $this->request->params['prefix'] == $prefix;
}
```

Explicando resumidamente o código acima: o `beforeFilter` (que é chamado antes de **chamar a action**) verifica qual prefixo da URL chamada utilizando o método `isPrefix`. Após detectar a URL, ele verifica se o prefixo é `admin`, se for, seta o layout `admin`, se não for permite o acesso a *todas urls* através do método `$this->Auth->allow();`.

Claramente, pra isso funcionar você deve ter o seu `Auth` configurado no `AppController`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public $components = array(
  'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate' => array(
      'Form' => array(
        'fields' => array('username' => 'password')
      )
    ),
    'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false),
    'logoutAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout', 'admin' => false),
    'loginRedirect' => '/admin',
    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false),
    'authError' => 'Acesso não permitido.'
  ),
  'Session',
  'RequestHandler',
  'Paginator'
);
```

Com tudo configurado como apresentado acima, suas URLs utilizando o prefixo `admin` estão seguras, ou seja, precisam do login do usuário.

### Limitando somente usuários do grupo Administrador

O jeito mais simples de fazer isso para atender a sua necessidade é da seguinte maneira.

Altere o método `beforeFilter()` para que ele verifique o `group_id` do Usuário logado (se ele estiver logado é claro), e se for o *id desejado*, você permite o acesso a URL.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
  if($this->isPrefix('admin')) {

    // Com a instrução abaixo, eu verifico se o usuário está logado
    if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {

      // Se estiver, verifico se está setado o group_id dele
      if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User.group_id')) {

        // Se ele tem um group_id, verifico se é igual ao desejado
        // Por exemplo: id do Administrador = 1
        if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User.group_id') == 1) {

          // Permite que ele acesse a URL

        } else {

          // Não permite o acesso a URL e redireciona o usuário
          // para uma página específica, neste caso a raiz do site
          $this->Session->setFlash(__('Você não tem permissão para acessar essa URL'));
          $this->Redirect('/');

        }
      }
    }

    // Seta o layout admin para as rotas administrativas
    $this->layout = 'admin';

  } else {

    // Utilizando o método abaixo, permite o acesso as URLs 
    // sem o login (Auth do CakePHP)
    $this->Auth->allow();

  }
}
```

Creio que seja isso.

Ficou extenso, mas creio que agora você já consiga seguir o caminho correto utilizando o CakePHP

---

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Qualquer dúvida, insiria um comentário abaixo.

Comment: O model a ser utilizado é o Admin. Em relação ao 3º ponto, estava a tentar passar o valor do post para essa variável. Eu achava que ao fazer o save da variável, o Cake fazia sozinho a associação. Devo dizer que estou ainda a aprender a utilizar o Cake. Lembrei-me de ver algo no site do Cake com um formato semelhante á correcção que fez, que de facto lá está, eu pensei que o cake tratava a informação daquela forma, não que tivesse de o fazer. Em relação ao 4 ponto, seria esse conteúdo no if seria algo tipo:  if($this->Admin->save($file)==true), misturada de outras soluções

Comment: @SunT Certo, mas como você já executou o save a 1ª vez, na 2ª é mais fácil validar através de um variável baseada na 1ª vez. Quanto as variáveis, o CakePHP precisa saber ao menos o NOME DO CAMPO, no caso você só falou `$file = 'valor'`, com isso você não está dizendo NADA ao CakePHP. Enfim, o que eu postei lhe ajudou, ou tem alguma dúvida em específico? Não hesite em perguntar.

Comment: No model basta ter esta linha `public $table = 'gallery_images';`  dentro da classe?

Comment: @SunT se você for usar o model ADMIN para salvar a GALLERY IMAGE, sim. Caso contrário deve fazer o `loadModel()` do `GalleryImage` e salvar utilizando ele: `$this->GalleryImage->save($file);`.

Comment: @SunT **apenas uma pergunta** para que eu possa editar a minha resposta de forma a te ajudar melhor. Qual model você está utilizando para salvar a Gallery Image? Admin? Ou você tem o model Gallery Image?

Comment: É assim, eu estou a usar o Model GalleryImage com o GalleryImagesController e o Model Admin com o AdminsControlelr. Agora estou na dúvida se estou a confundir as coisas, pois o model GalleryImage apenas está a servir para passar as imagens para uma action do GalleryImagesController. Será que deveria tratar do upload também? A forma como eu estou a fazer isto é de forma a que o model Admin trate de todas as acções realizadas pelo AdminsController, ou seja pelo administrador do site atravéz das ferramentas do painel de administrador.

Comment: @SunT creio que você está confundindo uma coisa: utilizar o AdminController pra representar a área administrativa. Não há necessidade de fazer isso. Vou reescrever minha questão.. aguarde alguns minutos.

Comment: @SunT demorei mais do que o previsto para lhe responder, mas peço que leia a minha resposta novamente do inicio ao fim, para entender claramente como as rotas funcionam no CakePHP, etc.

Comment: Desde já muito obrigado pela dedicação e trabalho que está a ter para me ajudar, e pelas explicações fantásticas. O código que deveria colocar na function admin_dashboard no PagesController remete para quê exactamente? Também ao fazer o insert na base de dados, o Cake está a enviar _Array_ como o conteudo para o campo path, `SQL Query: INSERT INTO 'pushup_app'.'gallery_images' ('path', 'modified', 'created') VALUES (Array, '2014-03-20 15:26:50', '2014-03-20 15:26:50')`.

Comment: @SunT erro meu: altere o seu código para o seguinte: `$file = $this->request->data['gallery_images']['path']['name'];` isso pois, da maneira que você/eu tinhamos colocado, ele estava pegando o array `$_FILES` e setando na varíavel. Agora neste caso, está pegando o `name` da imagem, porém, dessa exata forma pode ocorrer uma situação de outra imagem com o mesmo nome sobrescrever a sua. **Então recomendo que crie um hash, ou alguma combinação de valores**, por exemplo: sha1(data + hora (incluindo ms) + nome da imagem). Assim você consegue um nome único para a imagem.

Comment: @SunT não esqueça de marcar a resposta no final, caso tenha lhe ajudado.

Comment: Agora já não dá erro mas o nome não passa para a base de dados, apenas as datas. O pr() que fiz ao $file dá o nome da imagem correctamente. É algum problema com o model?

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13739/discussion-between-patrick-maciel-and-sunt)